# Alternatives to Apex SDK for Slack Integration Due to SLACK Feature Issue in Salesforce

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, slack, slack-salesforce-app, slack-app

I'm working on a Salesforce managed package for enhancing productivity with Slack integration. We've been using the Apex SDK for Slack (Beta), but encountered an issue: including "SLACK" in the features array of our project-scratch-def.json

```
  "features": [
    "EnableSetPasswordInApi","SLACK"
  ],
```

results in the error **"SLACK is not a valid feature value"** blocking the creation of new versions/scratch orgs.

Given this, has anyone else faced similar challenges with the SLACK feature or the Apex SDK for Slack? How did you address or work around these issues?

Furthermore, considering the potential discontinuation or lack of official support for the Apex SDK for Slack, we're contemplating alternative methods for integrating Slack. Does anyone have experience with or can recommend other approaches, involving Salesforce Flow Actions, for integrating Salesforce with Slack without the Apex SDK?

Appreciate any insights or shared experiences.